# pandas number of items in one column per value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. say for example, frame 1 is the student info:

```
student_id course
1          a
2          b
3          c
4          a
5          f
6          f
```

frame 2 is each interaction the student has with a program

```
student_id day   number_of_clicks
1          4     60
1          5     34
1          7     87
2          3     33
2          4     29
2          8     213
2          9     46
3          2     103
```

I am trying to add the information from frame 2 to frame 1, ie. for each student I would like to know the number of different days they accessed the database on, and the sum of all the clicks on those days. eg:

```
student_id course no_days total_clicks
1          a      3       181
2          b      4       321
3          c      1       103
4          a      0       0
5          f      0       0
6          f      0       0
```

I've tried to do this with groupby, but I couldn't add the information back into frame 1, or figure out how to sum the number of clicks. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we aggregate your `df2` to the desired information using `GroupBy.agg`. Then we `merge` that information into `df1`:

```
agg = df2.groupby('student_id').agg(
    no_days=('day', 'size'),
    total_clicks=('number_of_clicks', 'sum')
)

df1 = df1.merge(agg, on='student_id', how='left').fillna(0)

   student_id course  no_days  total_clicks
0           1      a      3.0         181.0
1           2      b      4.0         321.0
2           3      c      1.0         103.0
3           4      a      0.0           0.0
4           5      f      0.0           0.0
5           6      f      0.0           0.0
```

---

Or if you like one-liners, here's the same method as above, but in one line of code and more in `SQL` kind of style:

```
df1.merge(
    df2.groupby('student_id').agg(
    no_days=('day', 'size'),
    total_clicks=('number_of_clicks', 'sum')
    ),
    on='student_id',
    how='left'
).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the null values then aggregate using [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) as:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left').fillna(0, downcast='infer')\
        .groupby(['student_id', 'course'], as_index=False)\
        .agg({'day':np.count_nonzero, 'number_of_clicks':np.sum}).reset_index()


print(df)
   student_id course  day  number_of_clicks
0           1      a    3               181
1           2      b    4               321
2           3      c    1               103
3           4      a    0                 0
4           5      f    0                 0
5           6      f    0                 0
```

​